# Observable: Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value C#

Tags: c#, observable, anonymous-function, return-type

Im trying to get the content of multiple websites by using Observable and creating multiple subscriptions. I managed to get the contents but can't return the string from this method. What type of return is necessary for this Anonymous function?

```
public static void call(string url)
    {
        var query =
        from r in Observable.Using(
        () => new WebClient(),
        wc => Observable.Start(() => wc.DownloadString($"{url}")))
        select r;

        IDisposable subscription =
            query
                .Subscribe(r =>
                {
                    /*return r ? */
                });
    }
```

I first tried with `public static string call(string url)`
and also `public static Func<string>(string url)` but still not getting this right.

Comment: Subscribe only takes actions which have no return?

Comment: @KeithNicholas I want to return the string r when using the method Call

Comment: seems odd.   your function is designed in such a way that it setsup an observable so when the downloadstring happens it will callback..... your call function has long since exited back out when that happens

Comment: what you are asking for sounds like you just need to ditch Observable as it doesn't sound like it's what you want.

Comment: from what you have said you want, it could be done with  ```public static string Call(string url) => new WebClient().DownloadString(url);```